# Service Account Groups in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I was tracking down some permissions issues on SSRS 2012 and I started looking for the local groups that I am used to seeing for SQL Server.  I noticed something I had not seen before, the groups have changed in 2012.

[image: Windows Groups Screenshot]

I have checked on some of my other 2012 instances and am seeing similar.  Is everyone seeing this?

I have checked [BOL](http://bit.ly/K0SpJF) but am a finding it a little unclear.  I found this information from [Bob Beauchemin](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/Local-Windows-Groups-for-Service-Accounts-%28almost%29-gone-in-SQL-Server-2012.aspx).  It looks like he is seeing the same thing I did.

My question is, does everyone else running 2012 see the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon,
From what I've seen, the local Windows groups are going away in favor of using the NT SERVICE SIDs on W2K8R2 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx#Serv_SID

HTH,
Nancy Hidy Wilson

Comment: That is what I was seeing too but I guess I just didn't find the BOL clear.  Maybe I am just tired.  :-D.  Thank you for the quick reply.